# Display uialertview only once every day, week, month?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer

I was wondering if there is an easy way to display an alertview, but then not display it again until a week passes.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Checkout [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)